# Finding parametric vector form

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone please help me with a question? I cannot find an error in my working out. (for an alternative method)

**Question:** Find the parametric vector and Cartesian equation for the plane through $(2, 1, -2)$ perpendicular  to $(-1, 1, 2)$.

**Answer:** $(2, 1, -2) + s(-2, 2, -2) + t(3, 3, 0)$ ; $x - y - 2z = 5$.

I have found the Cartesian equation, but cannot find the parametric vector form.

Here is my working out:

**Method 1: Convert Cartesian to parametric vector form**

$x - y - 2z = 5$

Let y = $\lambda$ and z = $\mu$, for all real $\lambda$, $\mu$ to get

$x = 5 + \lambda + 2\mu$

This gives,

**x** = $
\begin{pmatrix}
5 + \lambda + 2\mu\\ 
\lambda\\ 
\mu
\end{pmatrix}$

**x** = $\begin{pmatrix}
5\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + \mu \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ for all real $\lambda$, $\mu$

That's not the answer, so I've lost. (maybe it IS, but it takes different set of ($\lambda$, $\mu$)?)

**Method 2: obtain the parallel vectors which when 'crossed', yield the normal vector, (-1, 1, 2)**

By definition, there exists a vector **x** in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix} = 0$

iff $x - y - 2z = 0$

Let y = $\lambda$ and z = $\mu$ for all real $\lambda$, $\mu$ to get

$x = \lambda + 2 \mu$

**x** = $\lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + \mu \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ for all $\lambda$, $\mu$

Putting this into parametric vector form,

$\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\ 
-1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} + \mu \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

Please, **any** help is **greatly** appreciated. :)

Comment: What you did is correct. The difference is certainly in the choice of the origine and the pair of vectors orthogonal with $(-1,1,2)$.

Comment: So how would I get the exact answer?

Comment: There isn' *the* exact answer, but a bunch of exact answers.